# column is ambiguous in multiple join postgresql

Tags: postgresql, codeigniter-3

if I remove the second join query, its works but otherwise not works !

> ERROR: column reference "category" is ambiguous LINE 1: ...tion",
>   "prefix_product"."full_desc" as "description", "category"... ^

```
SELECT "prefix_product"."id" as "product_id", 
       "prefix_product"."title" as "name", 
       "prefix_product"."short_desc" as "briefDescription",
       "prefix_product"."full_desc" as "description", 
       "category" as "productCategory" 
FROM "prefix_product" 
JOIN "prefix_category" 
   ON "prefix_product"."category"="prefix_category"."id" 
JOIN "prefix_category_attribs" 
   ON "prefix_product"."category"="prefix_category"."parent" 
WHERE "vendor" = '8'
```

I am using codeigniter3 with postgresql and in codeigniter, I have :

```
    $this->db->select(['prefix_product.id as product_id', 'prefix_product.title as name', 'prefix_product.short_desc as briefDescription', 'prefix_product.full_desc as description','category as productCategory']);
$this->db->where('vendor',$vendorId);
$this->db->from($this->tblName);
$this->db->join('prefix_category','prefix_product.category=prefix_category.id');
$this->db->join('prefix_category_attribs','prefix_product.category=prefix_category.parent');
$queryResult =$this->db->get()->result();
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there are more than one tables having the same column name, i.e. `category`. So you need to prefix column `category` in the `SELECT` clause in order to explicitly specify the table the column belongs to :

```
"prefix_product"."category" as "productCategory"
```